# How to send “Ctrl + Shift + t” in Sikuli?

Tags: python, sikuli

I'm having trouble to send the shortcut `CTRL + SHIFT + T` in Sikuli. 
This is what I typed:

```
type(Key.CTRL, Key.SHIFT, "t");
```

I want to do this shortcut to open a new tab on Chrome.

Comment: Check this question, it's Selenium related but it might be helpful to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905946/python-selenium-how-to-use-browser-shortcuts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type("t", Key.CTRL+Key.SHIFT)
```

as shown in the docs